# Purchasing an expiring .co.uk domain

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, expires

There is a `.co.uk` TLD that is currently expiring (it’s currently 45 days through its 90/92 day expiration period). I would like to purchase this domain when it comes on the open market.

I’ve looked into several domain name backordering services such as GoDaddy and others, after talking to most of the technical people at these companies they said they ping the domain once a day to see if it’s available (one of them said that they ping the domain several times a second, although I have my doubts about this company’s credibility).

Does anyone have any experience using domain backordering services, are they efficient?

From the sounds of it, if there is a domain I’d really like to purchase, would I be better just to setup a calendar alert and manually check the domain several times a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options in your case:

1. Try to contact the current owner and ask if they want to sell the domain to you.
2. Wait till the domain leaves the domain quarantine period and try to manually buy it.
3. Wait for a domain reseller to buy it and try to buy the domain for an (extremely) high price from this third party.

I also have my doubt about services who claim to check it multiple times a second. But i think checking the status every (few) minute(s) is realistic.

*The answer you choose could be based on how likely it is that this domain will be registered immediately after expiration. And weather it's possible to contact the current owner! I can imagine that it is not possible to contact the current owner when the domain is currently owned by a competitor.*

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain "Wait for a service like GoDaddy to buy it and buy the domain for an (extremely) high price from this third party." Dont they charge a flat rate i think its £30 in the UK, and only charge if you get the domain if not they refund the charge ?

Comment: You're right. I meant a "domain reseller". I changed the answer, thank you.